# Java ClassLoader getResource with special characters in path

Tags: java

I have the following problem. In our integration tests we use a different config which will be loaded from test resources with the following code prior to the tests:

```
URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("application.conf");
```

This works fine as long as there are no special characters in path. For example having the following correct path

```
D:/Dev/projects/#FLI/flinsta/fgraph/build/resources/test/application.conf
```

will result in the following wrong file path given by `getSystemResource`:

```
D:/Dev/projects/%23FLI/flinsta/fgraph/build/resources/test/application.conf
```

This then results in a file which simply doesn't exist. How can I make sure that something like this does not happen. Renaming the path is an option. However I would like to find a solution instead of a workaround.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: @WeareBorg this has nothing to do with encoding. The hashtag character gets escaped to it's Percent-Encoded version, not into a 'broken' character.

Comment: the URL is correct, it should be properly encoded. you need to decode it afterwards.

Comment: The difference is a file path vs a URL. `getSystemResource()` returns a URL, not a path. Some URLs will refer to locations inside jar files or on a webserver (usually for applets). Resources on the CLASSPATH are not always local files.

Comment: @bayou.io Was a foul. Ofc decoding helps! Thank you!

Comment: I have this same problem at jenkins but not my local. After I did some digging into it, I found that it certain class loaders build java.net.URL with special character, while some encode it. E.g. I am using maven-failsafe plugin which encodes the special character if `useManifestOnlyJar` is true, else it doesn't. Any idea about which classloaders encode the URL and which doesn't?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To answer my own question with the help of the comments:

```
URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("application.conf");
String configPath = URLDecoder.decode(resource.getFile(), "UTF-8");
```

Variable `configPath` then contains the correct path.

Comment: This will probably not work in all cases. The [javadocs of java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html) warn that " Note, the URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in certain circumstances. The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use URI, and to convert between these two classes using toURI() and URI.toURL()." They mention that URLDecoder is not always the right solution.